# One block cipher decryption with an AES and long key

Tags: java, encryption, aes, block-cipher

I was given this key in hex String: `"140b41b22a29beb4061bda66b6747e14"` and requested to decrypt an one block cipher with an AES implementing a ECB.

As we know, the key must be 16 bytes long. But the given key contains elements which  correspond to characters larger than one byte (e.g. `0xb2` whose char value is `²` corresponding to 2 bytes).

In fact, if I convert the hex String key into a key String I obtain `" A²*)¾´Úf¶t~ "`, then if I apply the method `key.getBytes().length` what I get is that the key is 21 bytes long.

My question is: is there any way to encrypt a 16 bytes long ciphertext with an AES given this key in Java?

Answer (score 1):

Your key looks correctly sized - just don't think of it as a string with meaningful characters. Instead, use a hex conversion method to convert it into a 16 byte array and use that as the key.

E.g.

```
String keyString = "140b41b22a29beb4061bda66b6747e14";
byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(keyString);
SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
```

Comment: We're still in full sync regarding points Duncan, quite amazing. PS I'm trying to have [tag:cipher] be a synonym for [tag:encryption]. I don't know how this exactly works, but if you find out how to vote on it it would be welcome...

Comment: @owlstead Yup, I've voted by going to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/encryption/synonyms and hitting the up-vote button. Good call. Race you to 20k :-)  A little strange that [tag:decryption] and [tag:decrypt] are synonyms of [tag:encryption] already...

Comment: @owlstead FYI - I opened a topic on that latter issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217994/decryption-tag-should-not-be-synonymous-with-encryption. I'd welcome your thoughts (not just asking for blind support here).